# Servlet and XQuery

Tags: servlets, exception, xquery, saxon

I wrote a java class to run a simple XQuery on a XML database (Using Saxon xqj). The query works well in this class. But I want to access this class from a servlet. The problem is that the servlet doesn't find the java class, It gets `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.xquery.XQException` when I run the servlet. Any Ideas please?

The Java class is as simple as This:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQConnection;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQException;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQPreparedExpression;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQResultSequence;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQSequence;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import net.sf.saxon.xqj.SaxonXQDataSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XMLClass {
public static String xmldata() throws XQException{
    XQConnection con;
    String output = null;
    final String sep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    String fileName= "cd_book.xml";
        con = new SaxonXQDataSource().getConnection();
        System.out.println("Connected");
    String queryString = "declare variable $docName as xs:string external;"+sep +
   "for $x in doc($docName)/*" +
   " return $x";
   XQPreparedExpression expr = con.prepareExpression(queryString);
   expr.bindObject(new QName("docName"), fileName, null);
   XQResultSequence rs = expr.executeQuery();
   String result =rs.getSequenceAsString(new Properties());
   return result;

    }
   }
```

And the Servlet is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQException;
public class ServletXML extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public ServletXML() {
    super();
}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException {

try {
        XMLClass.xmldata();
        } catch (XQException e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
 }

}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then xml your class may be missing from your classpath. How are you compiling and running this?

Also it is good practice to place both into one or more packages and import your class from your servlet if it is in a different package.

Comment: all the files are in the same package. If I remove the line which calls xmlData() method (in the ServletXML), then it doesn't get any exception. So I think the problem is that the servlet cannot access the method which has the XQuery written in it.

Comment: At the moment you have not specified a package. So how can all your files be in the same package? Also your method in the code you pasted is called `xmldata()` not `xmlData()`.